# How to store Nsmutablearray to SQL as json data and retrieve in ios (swift)

Tags: ios, mysql, json, nsmutablearray

Need to store Nsmutablearray to MySQL (phpmyadmin).

The array as a value in my dictionary

```
dict. SetValue (mutablearray, forKey: "mutable")
```

I save as in MySQL "BLOB" attribute

Saving:

```
Let Json: NSData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)

urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet())!

 // remaining code of JSON serialization and saving in PHP
```

But this is not working. When I retrieve it, it returns as "Array" string only.

I tried this too:

```
     let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(mutablearray)
```

Please let me know is there any way to store Nsmutablearry to sql and retrieve from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, are you going to store a JSON string of an array in your database at your server then retrieve it over HTTP/HTTPS?

Comment: s can you please give me the code

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not a database; it might be helpful to note which database system you're using.

Comment: sql using php code